# UISearchBar disappears from tableHeaderView when using beginUpdates/endUpdates

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I have a table view controller with a `UISearchController` that sets  `UISearchBar` as the `tableView.tableHeaderView`. When updating the search results, I use the `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` and related methods to update the data for the table view.

This makes the search bar disappear; the `tableHeaderView` is set to an empty, generic `UIView` of the same size as the search bar. If I simply use `reloadData` instead of the whole `beginUpdates`/`endUpdates` procedure, everything is fine.

The table view controller is embedded in a regular view controller; there is no navigation controller involved. This is the entire implementation of the table view controller necessary to reproduce the issue:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
}

- (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController
{
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Why does this cause the search bar to be replaced with a blank view, and how can it be avoided?

Comment: Did you try changing the "translucent" property on your viewController/Navigation controller on and of? I remember I had this issue once, And if I recall correctly "translucent" it had something to do with it..

Answer (score 0):

When you first click `UISearchController's` searchBar,it takes about 0.5s for the searchBar to animate. But  `self.tableView.endUpdates()` was called immediately by the delegate method, the animation was interrupted.
  The searchBar stuck in the middle of the animation,and you can't see it's UI:
[image]

A workaround is to check if searchBar is in animation,and delay `self.tableView.endUpdates()` when it's in .

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController){
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    //Do some updates

    if !searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton{
        self.tableView.performSelector(#selector(UITableView.endUpdates), withObject: nil, afterDelay: 1)

    }else{
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think you are onto something about animation. I have tried tricks like `[CATransaction setCompletionBlock:]`, but to no avail. Your workaround seems particularly hacky, and moreover does not work for the original problem. Probably because it's not as contrived as the reproducible example I provided, and does more work between `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates`.

Comment: In that case , you should try to init your 'UISearchController' with another tableViewController, and do all the updates with this second tableViewController.

Comment: As in `[[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:...]`? I suppose that's a solution, but I'd like to keep all the functionality tied to the original table view, like gestures and such. If there's no other way, there's nothing a little refactoring can't solve, though.

Comment: Then try to use UISearchBarDelegate `searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:`,and put your first `endUpdates` there.

Comment: Doing the work in `searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:` didn't seem to change anything, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Little revision about `beginUpdates, endUpdates and reloadData`

**beginUpdates :** : Begins a series of method calls that insert, delete, or select rows and sections of the table view.
Call this method if you want subsequent insertions, deletion, and selection operations (for example, cellForRowAtIndexPath: and indexPathsForVisibleRows) to be animated simultaneously. You can also use this method followed by the endUpdates method to animate the change in the row heights without reloading the cell. This group of methods must conclude with an invocation of endUpdates. These method pairs can be nested. If you do not make the insertion, deletion, and selection calls inside this block, table attributes such as row count might become invalid. You should not call reloadData within the group; if you call this method within the group, you must perform any animations yourself.

**endUpdates :** Concludes a series of method calls that insert, delete, select, or reload rows and sections of the table view.
You call this method to bracket a series of method calls that begins with beginUpdates and that consists of operations to insert, delete, select, and reload rows and sections of the table view. When you call endUpdates, UITableView animates the operations simultaneously. Invocations of beginUpdates and endUpdates can be nested. If you do not make the insertion, deletion, and selection calls inside this block, table attributes such as row count can become invalid.

**reloadData :** Reloads the rows and sections of the table view.
Call this method to reload all the data that is used to construct the table, including cells, section headers and footers, index arrays, and so on. For efficiency, the table view redisplays only those rows that are visible. It adjusts offsets if the table shrinks as a result of the reload. The table view’s delegate or data source calls this method when it wants the table view to completely reload its data. It should not be called in the methods that insert or delete rows, especially within an animation block implemented with calls to beginUpdates and endUpdates.

Now in case of search we don't know which rows are going to affect as well each time search result data would be different, I believe one shouldn't use

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

as its used when you are performing `insert, update or delete` operation on tableview and you know its `indexPath`.

Better use `[self.tableView reloadData];` as it will only update visible rows or section in tableview. Also refer Apple's Sample Code for [Table Search with UISearchController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableSearch_UISearchController/Listings/Objective_C_TableSearch_APLMainTableViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014683-Objective_C_TableSearch_APLMainTableViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_11), it also recommend to use `reloadData`.

Make respective changes and you are good to go.

Happy coding :)

Comment: I am aware that using `reloadData` makes the problem go away, although that does not explain why one can't use `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates`.

Comment: @Håvard thats what i have explained, when to use `beginUpdates and endUpdates` and `reloadData`.